# Rake Aborting on build-couchdb CouchDB Build

Tags: ruby, nosql, couchdb, rake

Trying to build CouchDB and I'm getting the following error:

```
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (2): [make ...]
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:995
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:1010:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:1010:in `sh'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:1094:in `sh'
/home/user/build-couchdb/tasks/lib.rb:163:in `gmake'
/home/user/build-couchdb/tasks/erlang.rake:83
/home/user/build-couchdb/tasks/lib.rb:219:in `with_autoconf'
/home/user/build-couchdb/tasks/erlang.rake:22
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/bin/rake:28
```

Not sure why, I have all the dependencies.  This is on Ubuntu 10.04, 64 bit Rackspace Server.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Have you verified that all the pre-reqs are on the system?

Comment: You should have a `rake.log` file now. Would you please attach that in the issue tracker? https://github.com/iriscouch/build-couchdb/issues Once I determine the issue, I will add an answer to help others solve it. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Jason-I started from scratch(fresh download) and that worked.  Not sure what I did  differently besides I ended up having to build another version of Spidermonkey in the end-but that didn't affect the Rake.